# What's wrong in my code for this output?

Tags: c, eclipse, output, symbols

My application is divided into Server and Client.

through the client (stdin) I write the values name, phone.

Server opens a txt file called "elenco" in which he writes the values.

my output is:

```
righetti
ilaria
à|÷UˇÄÈ 4648585858
```

why this strange symbols on telefono? ideas?

Here's my whole code,take a look and help me please.I'm going to crazy

http://pastebin.com/hsDu9S1H
http://pastebin.com/tzeUKd6C

Comment: Two problems: 1. Please post the code here instead of providing a link to it. 2. There is too much code. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The function `read` returns the number of bytes read. But you test for errors with `if (read(...) < 0)` which means that when 0 bytes are read you will get Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Also be aware that `read()` on a socket not necessarily returns the number of byte it was told to read. Carefully read `read()`'s documentation.

Comment: After `read(ds_sock, telefono, sizeof(telefono))` you print it as a string.What about a terminator?

Comment: Also^2  you are mentioning misbehaviour of the server and link the client's code ... :-S